# How to check if a method returns a non zero exit code in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile project that requires me to include an `'if statement` to ascertain if shell commands within certain methods return an exit code outside of `0`.

The first method `method 1` works as expected. However i would like to include an `if statement` to skip the second stage since that shell command in `method 2` doesn't exit with `0`.

```
def method1(setup){
  sh """
  echo ${setup}
  """
}
def method2(setup){
  sh """
   ech ${setup}
  """
}
node {
  stage('print method1'){   
    method1('paul')
  }
// I need an if statement to skip this method since the if statement returns non=zero

  stage('This method should be skipped'){   
   if(method2 returns != 0) //This if condition fails but need something similar to this
    method1('paul')
    }
}
```

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You use a default `sh` step execution in your example which means that exit code is not returned from the command. If exist status is something else than `0` in such case, pipeline fails with the exception. If you want to return exit status and allow the pipeline to continue you have to pass `returnStatus: true` option, for instance:

```groovy
int status = sh(script: """
    echo ${setup}
""", returnStatus: true)

if (status != 0) {
    // do something
}
```

*Source: [`sh` step pipeline documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)*